# NullPointerException al generar un tablero de Ajedrez

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

llevo poco estudiando java y estoy atascada con este ejercicio, tengo que crear un tablero de ajedrez en la que se especifiquen dos enumeraciones, ColorPieza siendo una enumeración simple y Tipo donde se añaden las piezas y el valor de ellas.
En la clase Pieza se representan los diferentes tipos de piezas y los colores.
El problema lo tengo en la clase Tablero donde al implementar el meétodo evalua, este tiene que devolver la suma de las piezas que existan en el tablero dependiendo del color. Muchas gracias de antemano.
Este es el código que tengo:

```
    public enum ColorPieza {
        BLANCO, NEGRO;
    }
    public enum Tipo {
        PEON (1),
        TORRE(5),
        CABALLO(3),
        ALFIL(3),
        DAMA(9),
        REY(0);
    
        private final int valor;
    
        Tipo (int valor){
            this.valor=valor;
        }
        public int getValor() {
            return valor;
        }
 public class Pieza {
    public ColorPieza color;
    public Tipo tipo;

    public Pieza(ColorPieza color, Tipo tipo){
        this.color=color;
        this.tipo=tipo;
    }


    public ColorPieza colorPieza(){
        return color;
    }

    public int TipoPieza(){
        return tipo.getValor();

    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return color.toString() +tipo.toString();
    }
} 
public class Tablero {
    private Pieza[][] tablero;
    private Tipo tipo;

    public Tablero(){
        tablero = new Pieza[8][8];
        setPiezas();
    }

    public void setPiezas(){
        tablero[0][0]=new Pieza(ColorPieza.BLANCO, Tipo.TORRE);
        tablero[0][1]=new Pieza(ColorPieza.BLANCO, Tipo.CABALLO);
        tablero[0][2]=new Pieza(ColorPieza.BLANCO, Tipo.ALFIL);
        tablero[0][3]=new Pieza(ColorPieza.BLANCO, Tipo.REY);
        tablero[0][4]=new Pieza(ColorPieza.BLANCO, Tipo.DAMA);
        tablero[0][5]=new Pieza(ColorPieza.BLANCO, Tipo.ALFIL);
        tablero[0][6]=new Pieza(ColorPieza.BLANCO, Tipo.CABALLO);
        tablero[0][7]=new Pieza(ColorPieza.BLANCO, Tipo.TORRE);
        tablero[1][0]=new Pieza(ColorPieza.BLANCO, Tipo.PEON);
        tablero[1][1]=new Pieza(ColorPieza.BLANCO, Tipo.PEON);
        tablero[1][2]=new Pieza(ColorPieza.BLANCO, Tipo.PEON);
        tablero[1][3]=new Pieza(ColorPieza.BLANCO, Tipo.PEON);
        tablero[1][4]=new Pieza(ColorPieza.BLANCO, Tipo.PEON);
        tablero[1][5]=new Pieza(ColorPieza.BLANCO, Tipo.PEON);
        tablero[1][6]=new Pieza(ColorPieza.BLANCO, Tipo.PEON);
        tablero[1][7]=new Pieza(ColorPieza.BLANCO, Tipo.PEON);
        tablero[6][0]=new Pieza(ColorPieza.NEGRO, Tipo.TORRE);
        tablero[6][1]=new Pieza(ColorPieza.NEGRO, Tipo.CABALLO);
        tablero[6][2]=new Pieza(ColorPieza.NEGRO, Tipo.ALFIL);
        tablero[6][3]=new Pieza(ColorPieza.NEGRO, Tipo.REY);
        tablero[6][4]=new Pieza(ColorPieza.NEGRO, Tipo.DAMA);
        tablero[6][5]=new Pieza(ColorPieza.NEGRO, Tipo.ALFIL);
        tablero[6][6]=new Pieza(ColorPieza.NEGRO, Tipo.CABALLO);
        tablero[6][7]=new Pieza(ColorPieza.NEGRO, Tipo.TORRE);
        tablero[7][0]=new Pieza(ColorPieza.NEGRO, Tipo.PEON);
        tablero[7][1]=new Pieza(ColorPieza.NEGRO, Tipo.PEON);
        tablero[7][2]=new Pieza(ColorPieza.NEGRO, Tipo.PEON);
        tablero[7][3]=new Pieza(ColorPieza.NEGRO, Tipo.PEON);
        tablero[7][4]=new Pieza(ColorPieza.NEGRO, Tipo.PEON);
        tablero[7][5]=new Pieza(ColorPieza.NEGRO, Tipo.PEON);
        tablero[7][6]=new Pieza(ColorPieza.NEGRO, Tipo.PEON);
        tablero[7][7]=new Pieza(ColorPieza.NEGRO, Tipo.PEON);
    }

    public int evalua(ColorPieza color) {
        int total = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < tablero[0].length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < tablero[1].length; j++) {
                if (tablero[i][j] != null) {
                    if (tablero[i][j].colorPieza().equals(color)) {
                            total += tipo.getValor();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }


        return total;
    }

    public double evalua() {
        int piezasBlancas = evalua(ColorPieza.BLANCO);
        int piezasNegras = evalua(ColorPieza.NEGRO);

        return piezasBlancas - piezasNegras;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En tu método public int evalua(ColorPieza color) hay un error

```
 total += tipo.getValor();
```

cambialo a :

```
total+= tablero[i][j].tipo.getValor()
```

Igualmente la condiciones dentro del bucle deberían estar en una misma linea.
*se puede usar equals: tablero[i][j].colorPieza().equals(color)*  **o** *tablero[i][j].color.equals(color)*

```
        for (int i = 0; i < tablero[0].length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < tablero[1].length; j++) {
            
            // Si la posicion [i][j] es null no evaluar
            
            if (tablero[i][j] != null && tablero[i][j].color ==color){ 
                System.out.println("Estoy en ["+i+"] ["+j+"] soy: "+tablero[i][j].color.name()); // probá
                //if (tablero[i][j].colorPieza().equals(color)) {
                    
                    total += tablero[i][j].tipo.getValor();
                    System.out.println();
                //}
            }
        }
    }
    return total;
}
```

No entiendo el ultimo método, resta dos int y retorna un double??

Comment: Muchas gracias!!! por más que le daba vueltas no lo veía.
En cuanto al último método, es verdad tiene que ser int, el double no tiene sentido.

Comment: Si la respuesta de Lucas te ha resultado útil, considera marcarla como "aceptada".

Comment: Ya está! perdona que no me había dado cuenta que no le había dado.